# How to find classification of a single image instance? (fastai)

Tags: image, machine-learning, computer-vision, classification, fast-ai

The code below creates a classifier from MNIST data set for 3 and 7 image digits.
Can you help me figure out how to use this learner to classify a new image?

```
!pip install -Uqq fastbook
import fastbook
fastbook.setup_book()

from fastai.vision.all import *
from fastbook import *

matplotlib.rc('image', cmap='Greys')
path = untar_data(URLs.MNIST_SAMPLE)
dls = ImageDataLoaders.from_folder(path)
learn=cnn_learner(dls,resnet18,pretrained=False,loss_func=F.cross_entropy,metrics = accuracy)
learn.fit_one_cycle(1,0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `learn.predict('testImage.jpg')`

For your reference, see the fastai docs [vision tutorial](https://docs.fast.ai/tutorial.vision#Multi-label-classification---Using-the-high-level-API)

Comment: I tried it, didn't work.
img = (path/'valid/3').ls()[0]
learn.predict(img)

Getting:
--> 233                 else [self.items[i_] for i_ in i])
IndexError: list index out of range

gets me the following error

Comment: from your error message it seems you are trying to access an item in a list that doesn`t exist. Can you check if your image path is correct?

Comment: I used  img = (path/'valid/3').ls()[0]  to make sure.

Comment: Is this not working for you `learn.predict(path/'valid/3')` ?

Comment: Getting the following
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/root/.fastai/data/mnist_sample/valid/3'

You can access the code and run it using this:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GYIweSLWaWKjXjNpH-s_ry24_y0O1GFT?usp=sharing

Comment: Also - To double check that the path I used for the file is correct I ran:
img = (path/'valid/3').ls()[0]
Image.open(img)
And the image shows up so 'img' is defined correctly

Comment: correct. I tried it as well as a specific image path. Didn't work